# Laravel php controller generate error

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

Why i am getting this error, here is my controller file,

squared code generate error, if I comment this code It'll save post to database

[image]

Here is error when i request to post, it give me error :

[image]

Comment: what is line 41 in your code?

Comment: please post the code as text in your question and not as a screenshot

Comment: Saw your code $post->is_public.......... I think its $posts->is_public

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong varaibale it should be **$posts->is_public**.

Answer (score 0):

check your

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

under your

{!! Form::hidden('id', $posts->id) !!}
```